# I use Django to return a template, but the outside css doesn't work

Tags: html, css, django

I return a html like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^station/$', views.stat_list)
]
```

And in html, I link to a css file and the root is right because I can see it working by directly open it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./station_list.css">
```

The image is the same problem:

```
<img src="logo.png" style="max-width:120px; max-height:50px;" />
```

Why is that the html can't use the outside link? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this documentation link for serving static files in django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/03/serving-static-files-in-django/